# ARB_draw_buffers available but not supported by shader engine

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to compile a fragment shader using:

```
#extension ARB_draw_buffers : require
```

but compilation fails with the following error:
extension 'ARB_draw_buffers' is not supported

However when I check for availability of this particular extensions, either by calling glGetString (GL_EXTENSIONS) or using OpenGL Extension Viewer I get positive results.

OpenGL version is 3.1,
The grapic card is Intel HD Graphics 3000.

What might be the cause of that?

Comment: make sure to update your graphic card driver, it may be supported bu the vendor but not by the driver

Comment: Hmm, so if glGetString (GL_EXTENSIONS) asks the driver for the available extensions, from which source does #extension method gets a list of supported extensions?

Comment: Obviously the glGetString queries for capability ( it's deprecated btw) if it returns the arb_draw_buffers this means that this profile is supported by the hardware, rest the driver then supports or not this capability. Check the driver version on Intel website

Comment: This functionality is standard in OpenGL 3.1. No need to bother with extensions to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your driver in this scenario is 3.1; it is not clear what your targeted OpenGL version is.

If you can establish OpenGL 3.0 as the mininum required version, you can write your shader using `#version 130` and avoid the extension directive altogether.

The ARB extension mentioned in the question is only there for drivers that cannot implement all of the features required by OpenGL 3.0, but have the necessary hardware support for this one feature.

That was its intended purpose, but there do not appear to be many driver / hardware combinations in the wild that actually have this problem. You probably do not want the headache of writing code that supports them anyway ;)